# How to install clockworkmod recovery on Asus memopad 8 me181c?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

How to install clockworkmod recovery on Asus memopad 8 me181c? or Can't I?
My device was rooting.
Clockworkmod doesn't support Asus memopad 8 me181c, but Have the people of the volunteer made clockworkmod for my device?
I searched how to install, but I haven't found how to install it.

<sup><sup>I can't speak English well. If you can't understand this post, I don't mind asking me.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/asus-memo-pad-8-me181c-tethered-cwm-t3006382) on XDA Developers. But it a tethered recovery. Read carefully before attempting to do anything.